# Organzing javascript / jQuery for multiple web pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, module

To keep organized, I'd like to keep all the javascript for my site in a single file:

```
scripts.js
```

However, some of my scripts are only used on on some pages, other scripts are only used on other pages.

In my document-ready function it looks like this:

```
function home_page() {
  // image rotator with "global" variables I only need on the home page
}

$('#form')... // jQuery form validation on another page
```

The problem with this, is that I am getting javascript to execute on pages it's not even needed. I know there is a better way to organize this but I'm not sure where to start...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do something like this, or some variation (a little pseudo code below) :

```
var site = {
    home: {
       init: function() {
           var self=this; //for some reference later, used quite often
           $('somebutton').on('click', do_some_other_function);
           var externalFile=self.myAjax('http://google.com');
       },
       myAjax: function(url) {
           return $.getJSON(url);
       }
    },
    about: {
       init: function() {
           var self=this;
           $('aboutElement').fadeIn(300, function() {
               self.popup('This is all about me!');
           });
       },
       popup: function(msg) {
           alert(msg);
       }
    }
};
$(function() {
    switch($('body').attr('class')) {
       case 'home':
          site.home.init(); 
       break;
       case 'about':
          site.about.init();
       break;
       default: 
          site.error.init(); //or just home etc. depends on the site
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

One thing you could do would be to use classes on the `<html>` or `<body>` tag to establish the type of each page. The JavaScript code could then use fairly cheap `.is()` tests before deciding to apply groups of behaviors.

```
if ($('body').is('.catalog-page')) {
  // ... apply behaviors needed only by "catalog" pages ...
}
```

Even in IE6 and 7, making even a few dozen tests like that won't cause performance problems.

Answer (score 1):

I ususally have an `init()` function that goes something like this:

```
function init() {

    if($('#someElement').length>1) {
         runSomeInitFunction()
    }
    ... more of the same for other elements ...

}
```

Basically just check to see if the element exists on the page, if it does, run its own initialization function, if not, skip it.

The whole JS codes is cached by the browser after the first page load anyway, so there's no point in fragmenting your JS file down into page-specific pieces. That just makes it a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

You could use for each page object literals to get different scopes.

```
​var home = {

    other: function() {

    },

    init: function() {

    }
};

var about = {

    sendButton: function(e) {

    },        

    other: function() {

    },

    init: function() {

    }
}

var pagesToLoad = [home, about];
pagesToLoad.foreach(function(page) {
   page.init();
});​
```

Comment: I like this approach but **how** do I detect if the page is a home page or an about page? The other two methods detect by selector (which I am familiar with) but I am not as familiar with your method...